# Can't made python macro to work, just does a infinite loop

Tags: python, listener, pyautogui

My goal here is to make a script that when you type "medo1" it types automatically the text present inside the for loop. But apparently, last5 couldn't be changed at all and this function are running by it's own by typing something itself. Any help?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener;import pyautogui as pa,time as t

musics=['medo1=link1','medo2=link2','medo3=link3','medo4=link4','medo5=link5']
last5=['a','a','a','a','a']

def on_press(key):
    if key==Key.esc:return
    global last5
    d='aaaaa'

    try:last5.append(key.char);last5.pop(0);d=''.join(last5)
    except:pass
    for m in musics:
        if d in m:
            pa.press('backspace',presses=99);pa.typewrite('b.p '+m.split('=')[1]);t.sleep(0.03);pa.press("enter")
            pa.typewrite('b.loop all');t.sleep(0.1);pa.press("enter");last5=['a','a','a','a','a'];break

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:listener.join()
```

I was trying to make it work by typing "medo1" and it did, but it enters on a infinite loop that I must delete the terminal inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you want the code stop executing after the if condition is true ?

Comment: no, I want it to listen endlessly, but type only one time.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, if you want to just type only once ? why listen to it endlessly ? Anyways Take a look at my answer and see if it is what you meant

Comment: If it doesn't work, let me know

Answer (score 2):

The problem was your listener is listening to itself, and as for the problem with CHF's Answer, it occurs to be that we can't just stop and start the listener. In the below code, we are entirely starting another listener after stoping the current one.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener;import pyautogui as pa,time as t

musics=['medo1=link1','medo2=link2','medo3=link3','medo4=link4','medo5=link5']
last5=['a','a','a','a','a']

loopedOnce=False

def on_press(key,listener):
    if key==Key.esc:return
    global last5,loopedOnce
    d='aaaaa'

    try:last5.append(key.char);last5.pop(0);d=''.join(last5)
    except:pass
    for m in musics:
        if d in m:
            listener.stop()
            pa.press('backspace', presses=99)
            pa.typewrite('b.p ' + m.split('=')[1])
            t.sleep(0.03)
            pa.press("enter")
            pa.typewrite('b.loop all')
            t.sleep(0.1)
            pa.press("enter")
            last5 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
            loopedOnce=True
            break

# Collect events until released
while not(loopedOnce):
    with Listener(on_press=lambda key: on_press(key, listener)) as listener: listener.join()
    loopedOnce=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by changing line 14 to: "if d == m.split('=')[0]:".
The problem indeed was that the script was self calling, but solved by only comparing the command part "m.split('=')[0]" which refers to "medo1". While typing, it accidentaly types the "link1" part.